# Spectroscopy from a classical light wave or photon only?

Tags: electromagnetism, visible-light, solid-state-physics, maxwell-equations, spectroscopy

In chemistry we mostly regard light/electromagnetic radiation as a beam of particles or photons. This is a very useful model to explain molecular excitations and ionisations from quantum interactions. However, I am wondering how far the electromagnetism model of light as a propagating disturbance will get us?

My university friend who studies physics assures me that Maxwell's laws are among some of the most beautiful in all of physics. To this end I am excited to find areas where we can share this view. But most of my degree focuses on light-matter interactions from the photon model only e.g scattering techniques.

In particular imagine some spectroscopy technique,

- My approach would be to describe a light scattering model from the collision of incident photons with electrons, energy exchange and promotion or relaxation to a virtual state and photon emission.
- The alternative is an electromagnetic field that encounters static charges and superposes into a resultant field.

I am not familiar with this second approach and was hoping for a little introduction to the classical model applied to the spectroscopy of solids/molecules etc. Thank you for your time.

Comment: This is a beautiful but complex question. We have developed "shortcuts" in our description of the physical world - where sometimes we use waves, and sometimes particles - simply because it would complicate matters (without increasing our understanding) to try and express the full duality in all scenarios. That doesn't mean this is not a good question - but it might turn out to be hard to get a satisfactory answer.

Comment: The problem with this is that you would be describing things that don't exist. Neither photons nor electrons are hard balls and the collision picture is basically a classical approximation that doesn't describe what really happens. The other question is why we need more descriptions of well understood phenomena, to begin with? Wouldn't you be spending your time better on researching something that is not already 100% understood?

Comment: @CuriousOne, I do not think your comment has much to do with the question. The question does not insist that photons or electrons are hard balls. The question also does not ask for what "really happens". To answer your question, we need more descriptions of all phenomena, because learning another point of view trains the brain and having another point of view at out disposal enhances our possibilities, both as to applications and as to development of physics. Claiming anything in physics is '100% understood' is ridiculous.

Comment: @RedPen, what you're asking is a vast topic of physics, it is not possible to explain it here. Search for the Lorentz-Drude model, classical theory of dispersion, classical theory of absorption.

Comment: @JánLalinský: The OP is seems, more or less, be thinking of these phenomena as classical particle or wave scattering processes. The answer to that is "they are neither" and training the brain to limit itself to two insufficient views of a phenomenon that is perfectly explained by a third, already, is poor training. The basic processes in atomic spectroscopy are as nearly 100% understood as anything in physics ever can be. Now, I did invite the OP in my comment to think about things that are not understood and would welcome experimental suggestions invalidating QM but that is not his proposal.

Comment: @JánLalinský: All of those models are approximations of physics that has been used to predict the anomalous magnetic moment of the electron to 14 digits of precision... that's simply not where the music plays these days.

Comment: Thank you both for your suggestions, I have only just heard about classical electrodynamics so I am very excited to learn how to apply it to my own subject of molecules and crystals. I appreciate it will be limited in use and not correct compared what you are suggesting CuriousOne but I feel that QED would be another language to me at the moment (if that is what you were suggesting?). Thank you both very much for your help, I really appreciate it! :)

Comment: @CuriousOne, you are making too many private assumptions and then sharing your conclusions.

Comment: @JánLalinský: I can only go by the things that the OP says. (S)he could have told us about her plans to describe atomic spectroscopy using quantum electrodynamics, but she didn't, from which I can only discern that she is still thinking about it in classical terms, which is flat out wrong but still taught in classes for physicists and chemists alike. I, for instance, never heard the words "Feynman path integral" uttered in a single undergrad class and I had to learn about these STANDARD things myself. Here, of course, we can get the OP the right information right away.

Comment: Just the fact a model does not use ideas of quantum field theory does not invalidate it; only internal inconsistency or contradiction with experience does. In my experience, thinking about spectroscopy in classical terms is very valuable.

Comment: The wave picture of scattering at the atomic level isn't really well suited to *"a little introduction"* At bigger scales the Huygens-Fresnel infrastructure works pretty well. Pick any physics text on optics.

Comment: Any work along these lines would only touch on the **interpretation** of quantum mechanics. It would not contribute at all to theory of the physical phenomena itself. If @RedPen aims to be a philosopher of science instead of a scientist, this would be a step in the direction.

Answer (score 0):

**How much of physics can be explained by quantum mechanics alone**.

99% of what is explained on PSE with QM is about the double-slit experiments and the interaction of atoms, subatomic and elementary particles.  The latter starts from the equations of the spectra of EM radiation (Balmer, ...) and Planck blackbody radiation and infers the distribution of electrons around the nucleus.

**Where we are**.

The slit experiments show a distribution pattern on the screen with a periodic intensity described by a wave equation. Everything else is interpretation, because we have no instrument for a direct measurement that does not affect the propagation path. In addition, the spherical wave (Huygens' principle) behind an obstacle does not exist. The deflection of particles behind a single slit is blanked out to the left and right of the slit, while in the case of water waves it propagates through all 180° behind the slit.

Bor's premise about orbits was wrong and the application of spectral line distribution (especially or even exclusively of hydrogen) to atomic structure is not in agreement with the periodic table of elements. We still apply the Balmer and Rydberg formulas of the emission lines of hydrogen to the electron distribution for all elements. There is a clear periodicity of chemical behavior for 2, 8, 8, 18, and 18 elements and QM needs a lot of additional rules to agree with the PTE.

**Some suggestions**.

The *magnetic dipole of the electron* plays the main rule in electron distribution in atoms. Chemist Gilbert N. Lewis' cubic model for the second and third periods and Paulis' principle are a good place to start. At four edges of the cube the magnetic dipoles are directed inward (spin down) and at the other edges outward. Perfect symmetry.

The electron is not only equally equipped with a magnetic and an electric field. However, the electric field is partially stripped off as it approaches the nucleus. The emitted photons arise from the energy of the electric field of the electron and the corresponding protons.  The discreteness of the photon emission indicates the possibility that the emission is stopped near the nucleus. There is no longer an energy packet in the electric field of the electron-proton system sufficient for photon emission. This would explain the stability of the atoms.

Last but not least, particle passage through slits for **photons and the subatomic particles** should be investigated in different materials and at applied electric potential or a magnetic field. The observation of a quantized interaction between the surface electrons of the slit and the passing particles would put an end to the agonizing discussion about the spooky behavior in inference experiments. Incidentally, while interference does indeed occur in water waves, such an explanation for photons is untenable today. Light in the low intensity range does not interact.

Comment: "because we have no instrument for a direct measurement that does not affect the propagation path" Lack of instruments is not the reason. The reason is that any setup that distinguishes between the two slits directly prohibits interference.

Comment: "Bor's premise about orbits was wrong" Bohr's model was a crucial step towards quantum mechanics. It was a pragmatic approach. This is 20/20 hindsight vision.